# Periodic function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ (continuous if possible ) such that the sequence $\{f(n) \}$ is not constant and convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

Does there exist a periodic function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that the sequence $\{f(n) \}$ is not constant and convergent ? Does there exist such a continuous function ?

Comment: Is a constant function okay?

Comment: Any function with period $1$ (or a fraction of $1$)

Comment: sorry for that , I have edited

Answer (score 2):

No.

Assume $f(n)\to c$.
Let $p>0$ be a period of $f$. 
The sequence $n\bmod p$ is either dense in $[0,p)$ or discrete.

In the latter case, $\{f(n)\}$ is a periodic sequence of numbers, which is convergent iff it is constant.

On the other hand in the former case, all tails (i.e., $\{n\bmod p\mid n>N\}$) are also dense, which implies that for any $\epsilon>0$ the set $f^{-1}((c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon))$ is dense in $\mathbb R$. This implies $f(x)=c$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Sorry , I didn't get that $n \mod p$ thing ...

Answer (score 0):

For a nonconstant example, let $z$ be an irrational number and $\{a_i\}$ be a nonconstant convergent sequence.  Consider the equivalences classes of $\mathbb{R}$ under $\mathbb{Q}z$ where $x$ and $y$ are equivalent iff their difference is a rational multiple of $z$.  Observe that for any integers $n\not=m$, $n$ and $m$ are in different classes because their difference is $n-m\not\in\mathbb{Q}z$.

We will define a fuction that is constant on these classes.  Define the function 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}a_n&x\text{ is equivalent to $n$}\\0&\text{no such $n$ exists}\end{cases}
$$
This function is periodic because $f(x+z)=f(x)$ and the sequence $f(n)=a_n$ is nonconstant and convergent.

The continuous case is not possible because the period $p$ must not be rational (because then the sequence would be periodic and periodic convergent sequences are constant), but then the image of $\mathbb{Z}$ will be dense in the quotient $\mathbb{R}/p$ (two real numbers are identified if their difference is a multiple of $p$), so $f(n)$ will be arbitrarily close to all values in its image infinitely often, but then if $f$ is not constant, $f(n)$ will be arbitrarily close to two different values and cannot be convergent.